# cannot write korean in game on linux mint

Tags: linux-mint, steam, games

I can't write korean in games on linux mint

I use UIM as writer

I can write korean in OS, like search box of setting or terminal, however i cannot write korean in games

Games i tried is minecraft and Team fortress 2

They display korean correctly, but i can't write it

Copy-Paste works

Writing korean on steam only works in Big picture mode. and i can't send korean message to my friends even with Big picture mode

Comment: I don't know much about this, but I would think those applications would honor it if your locale is set correctly. You can see what it's currently set to by running the `locale` command in a terminal. If it's set correctly and those applications are not honoring it, then that seems like a valid bug to report to them. If it isn't set correctly, I don't know how to fix it, but it should be relatively simple to figure out.

Comment: they are all ko_kr.UTF-8. In fact, not only korean, but also japanese and chinese character have exact same problem. they can be displayed, but can't be written by user